# Cannot install XCode 4.3.2 on 10.7.5 running on VMWare Fusion 7.1.1

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, vmware-fusion

I have installed OSX 10.7.5 on VMWare fusion 7.1.1 and it is running fine. When I try and install XCode 4.3.2 or 4.3.3 on it, the installation fails.

The "XCode Component Installation" screen just shows "Mobile Device Framework" as the one that XCode is going to install. When I click on "Install" on that screen, the installation fails with the message:

"An unknown error occurred. See the install log for more details."

I have reasons to stick to 10.7.x and Xcode 4.3.2 and theoretically this combination should work.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the certificate used to sign the package now being expired. See [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45841/xcode-4-2-snow-leopard-doesnt-install) for a solution (in short: set your date back a few years)